# Reasonable source of old proof-of-concept attacks

Tags: attacks, exploit, vulnerability

I am relatively new to the area of cyber security but have a reasonable knowledge of several programming languages, assembly (x86 in particular) and scripting. In light of the recent Shellshock and GHOST vulnerabilities I thought it might be interesting to study older CVEs and security reports and find some old POC code that showed how the vulnerabilities (and attacks) worked, particularly on systems I use less frequently.

I fully understand why more recent vulnerabilities do not necessarily have publicly accessible exploit examples - but are there any archives (Internet or otherwise) of POC (or similar) attacks on old security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically exploits are released on the Full Disclosure Mailing list, or another email list. Everything's archived online, so a little clever Googling will take you to the original announcements.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://exploit-db.com it has lots of exploit codez